# Chrome Extension closes after window created by the extensions is closed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, paypal, popupwindow

We are currently working on a chrome extension where we have social sign in and PayPal integrated.

Recently we found a weird behavior running Chrome on Mac OS.

When the extensions creates a popup window (PayPal Smartbuttons, identity.launchWebAuthFlow) and this popup window is closed either through success action or by the user, our extension window gets also closed and we cannot get any events from these Actions.

For example, on PayPal the payment is done but we cannot capture it since the smart buttons are rendered in the popup.js but the extension is closed after PayPal closes the popup window and so no callback is fired.

Does someone have a similar behavior? For us its only on Mac, Windows works.

best

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution back then?

Comment: Same issue here - seems as if no one knows.